# Cannot convert Rcpp::sugar::Plus_Vector_Primitive to Rcpp::traits::storage_type

Tags: r, rcpp, armadillo

I am basically trying to translate some `R` code into `cpp` using `Rcpp`. I got the following errors in the code below:

```
error: cannot convert ‘Rcpp::sugar::Plus_Vector_Primitive<14, true, Rcpp::stats::D2<14, true, Rcpp::Vector<14, Rcpp::PreserveStorage> > >’ to ‘Rcpp::traits::storage_type<14>::type {aka double}’ in assignment
```

Here is the code

```
 #include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

// [[Rcpp::export(".loop_exp")]]
void mm_mult(const arma::vec& helpa, const arma::mat& helpb, const arma::vec& helpc,
             const Rcpp::NumericVector& t1, const arma::vec& t2, int J, Rcpp::NumericVector& prob)
{
  int j;
  for (j = 1; J <= J; j++)
  {
    arma::mat t = (helpb.row(j)).t() * (t2);
    double tt = t[0,0];
    prob[j] = (helpa[j] + dnorm(t1, tt, helpc[j]));  <---- here is the error 
  }

  return;
}
```

I guess this is a type casting error, but basically I cannot find a good reference.. Could anyone give me some help on this issue? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is that the `dnorm` "syntaxic sugar" has a signature `NumericVector dnorm( NumericVector, double, double )`.

As it returns a `NumericVector`, you have to convert it to a `double` value yourself.

A quick and easy (and not very robust) way is to subset the returned vector to get only its first element. In your example:

```
prob[j] = (helpa[j] + dnorm(t1, tt, helpc[j])[0]); // Note the "[0]"
```

Otherwise, there are a couple of other potential problems in your code: you shouldn't `#include <Rcpp.h>` as it is already done with `#include <RcppArmadillo.h>` --- also, your loop ending condition, `J <= J`, looks suspicious to me...

Hope this helps :)

Comment: While this solves the compilation error, thinking more about it, what you probably meant was to store the `j-th` element, with either `prob[j] = (helpa[j] + dnorm(t1, tt, helpc[j])[j]);` or `prob[j] = (helpa[j] + dnorm(t1[j], tt, helpc[j])[0]);`

Comment: An alternative is provided by the _scalar_ variant in the `R` namespace:  `R::dnorm()` -- see file `Rmath.h`.